# How can I not forget university mathematics?

Tags: mathematics

I am a first year undergraduate student of mathematics. Nevertheless, I have (self-)studied a total of 19 (UG and PG) books, cover to cover already, at home not in classes. The method of studying was to study a book (i.e. for first time) without doing the exercises with understanding at least 80% of it; in other words, "reading" or not involving in all technicalities. Afterwards, for second time I analysed every line of the book with doing all exercises.

However, even with twice study I have forgotten almost all of the 19 books. To be precise, if I take a test one week after I am finishing a book (the second cycle of studying) I would get a *perfect* score; on the other hand, if I take a test about 6 months after that initial test I would get 5%-10% score!

Quite the opposite, I do remember every mathematics that I have learned in high school and I will probably remember after 20 years!

I thought about that quite a lot and I cannot figure that out why is there such a big difference. Or more practically, what can I do to learn university mathematics as 'mind-sticky' as high-school mathematics?

Comment: A good opportunity to memorize university mathematics is transforming abstract knowledge into simpler to grasp stories. All what you have to do is searching for some colleagues, and tell them a narrative of how do you learned mathematics and why you have done so. Stories become more realistic if they are explained with details, for example you can describe the color of the first logarithm table in detail or explain how it feels to study the subject at university level.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for matheducators.stackexchange.

Comment: "Learning" math by reading a book without doing exercises is like "learning" to swim by watching the Olympics. The first time you'll try to get in the water, you'll drown. It's impossible to know that you've "understood 80%" if you don't try to apply that knowledge.

Comment: Apply it to real problems then it has a link to stick to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to learn anything you need to cause physical changes in the brain. This requires repetition and reinforcement. The brain actually re-wires itself by forming new connections between neurons. Your initial reading is probably doing little for you as you just pass over the material. If you read, for example, The Iliad, it is a nice story, but you won't remember much of the detail of it after you finish. Only a few things will stand out. And mathematics is worse because it is the connections between things that are essential.

Your second pass, doing all the exercises is better, but apparently not enough.

Engage with the material.

As you study take notes as you go. Summarize each chapter of the book. Write down the three most important ideas in each chapter. Better yet, each time you have a "study session" write down what you think are the most important ideas (but not everything). When you finish, go over those notes again and write down the three most important ideas.

When you go back to study for another session. Try to remember what the important ideas were from the previous session. If you can't go back and review your notes.

Periodically, review your notes. You don't have anyone to give you an exam, which is the trick professors use to get you to review, so you will have to make that part of your regular process.

If you take notes on index cards you can carry your summary cards with you for review. If you have to wait for anything for a few minutes, you can pull out your cards and shuffle through them. You can also rearrange them and create mini-decks of important ideas.

But the idea is to force the important concepts from short term memory into long term. Memorization isn't the goal, however. It is making the remembered ideas useful. Connecting one idea to another. A math problem seldom depends on only a single idea for solution. You need to combine them. Memorization alone won't do that for you, but solving lots of problems will. There used to be (and may still be) books you could buy that had nothing in them but exercises. I once used those books to help solidify my knowledge.

You can also make up problems for yourself. If you want to know what, for example, derivatives can tell you about the shape of a curve/function of a certain kind, graph a lot of such functions by hand, on paper. If you graph, say, 100 rational functions by hand using the first and second derivatives, you will get a feel both for rational functions and for derivatives.

It is that sort of reinforcement that leads to learning.

Comment: A truly excellent and comprehensive answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

19 UG and PG books is like a total math education through a MS. To cover that in less then a year or two, without professional support to guide you through the tricky spots and correct any fundamental mistakes, means you are going way to fast. To really learn material, you need time to digest it. To expect to learn a book/topic a month is not reasonable. Given the number of exercises in a typical math book, I would expect even an experienced mathematician to struggle to complete them in a month.

Comment: I have finished 19 books in 4 years before entering university in my high school times.

Answer (score 1):

Estimating well one is know mathematics is tricky. I offer some ideas for figuring out whether you are learning all the material you go through and whether you are actually forgetting it. (The questions are something you should think about, as this website is not intended for extended dialogue.)

## How well do you do in classes?

You are doing a huge amount of self-study, which show in your performance in mathematics and mathematically oriented classes, like physics and statistics. How are they going? Compare also with your peers. If you excel at them, it is a good sign that you are learning things and not forgetting them immediately. If they do not go well, there is a problem in your study methodologies and you should fix that.

## Is it easier to learn a subject that builds on top of a previous one?

When I took the first linear algebra course, which was about calculations with matrices and vectors and some proofs, I did not feel I understood anything (in spite of getting a good grade). On the next linear algebra course with abstract linear spaces I noticed that the material from the previous course was easy and I had in fact learned it. This pattern repeated, for me.

Typically, in your mathematics studies, you learn the same thing over and over again, in more and more abstract settings. If you can grasp the idea in an abstract setting, it usually means you have also learnt it in the less abstract one (even if it did not feel like that). How does this work for you?

## Memorization and re-learning

You are not supposed to remember all details of mathematics by heart. Rather, you are supposed to be able to reason about it on a more general level ("Is this true?" "Could I prove this?") and maybe be able to reconstruct an identity or theorem by considering typical examples and counter-examples and coming up with a proof, given time. Some proofs are difficult and hard to come up with, while many are manageable. Also, when you do need a theory you have studied before, you should be able to re-learn it very quickly.

## How to learn mathematics

Do lots of calculations and exercises. When facing a definition, try to come up with an example and a non-example. When facing a theorem, try to see if you can remove or weaken the assumptions and see what, if anything, goes wrong.

There has been much more written about this and it is too broad a question to answer here.